# E-bike battery doesn't work anymore, where do I get this specific one?

Tags: identify-this-bike, battery, electric-bike

Can somebody tell me exactly what battery this is or where I can buy it? I appreciate any help a lot!
If you need more information, please let me know.

[image]

**Edit:**
This is the e-bike the battery used to. Does anyone know this e-bike?

[image]

Comment: You should try asking on https://endless-sphere.com/forums/ . it is a forum that specializes in e-bikes. You will find people much more knowledgeable on e-bikes there.

Comment: Looks like this question will be closed for being Off Topic.  You might get some other answers from the electrical-focussed stacks.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an exact answer - most of us ride plain old human-powered bikes, but you can tell from the label its a 36V Nickel Metal Hydride battery with a total capacity of 8 Amp-hours.

Most ebikes these days are Lithium Polymer variations, for weight and power density reasons.  So I suspect your bike is getting a little old.

If the manufacturer doesn't sell batteries any more, you may be able to "repack" this one with new cells.  Its a little hands-on, and requires you to bust-open this package carefully, and swap the EOL cells inside for new ones of the same chemistry and rating and specs.

There are companies who do this sort of repacking for power tools, but in today's throw away and planned obsolescence society, it is often cheaper to replace the battery pack (if you can find it).

Can you go back to the place where you got the bike originally?

If you find an answer, please add your own answer to your question.

Comment: E-bike manufacturers and dealers tend to come and go, and designs change quite quickly so the dealer isn't likely to be much use. The manufacturer might be but support is often rather limited. For both Li and lead acid, balancing is an issue so professional repacking would be a good idea. That's less important with NiMH (which were never common on bikes).

Comment: @ChrisH luckily this is a NiMH battery.

Comment: @Aron I put it in because I don't *think* it's completely unnecessary for NiMH, though you *might* get away with buying matched batteries and the failure modes of NiMH tend to be a gradual loss of capacity rather than the dead cells with some chemistries.